# How to get 8 columns in my second tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my html code: http://jsfiddle.net/Udxyb/417/

In the above code i am having four columns in first tr (eg:section1,section2,section3,section4).but in the next tr of my table i want 8 columns with same width as of first tr (eg: item 111, item 112,item 113,item 114,item 115,item 116,item 117,item 118).

```
<table id="main_table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="firstline">
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="width:1002px; background-color:green; color:white">
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 3 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 111</td>
            <td>item 112</td>
            <td>item 113</td>
            <td>item 114</td>
            <td>item 115</td>
            <td>item 116</td>
            <td>item 117</td>
            <td>item 118</td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 121</td>
            <td>item 122</td>
            <td>item 123</td>
            <td>item 124</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 131</td>
            <td>item 132</td>
            <td>item 133</td>
            <td>item 134</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 3 </td>             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 211</td>
            <td>item 212</td>
            <td>item 213</td>
            <td>item 214</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 221</td>
            <td>item 222</td>
            <td>item 223</td>
            <td>item 224</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 231</td>
            <td>item 232</td>
            <td>item 233</td>
            <td>item 234</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 3 </td>
             <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 311</td>
            <td>item 312</td>
            <td>item 313</td>
            <td>item 314</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 321</td>
            <td>item 322</td>
            <td>item 323</td>
            <td>item 324</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 331</td>
            <td>item 332</td>
            <td>item 333</td>
            <td>item 334</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {


    $("#polls").on("click", ".flip", function() {

        $(this)

            .closest('tbody')
            .next('.section')
            .toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `colspan="2"` on all the cells in the rows that have four cells.

Comment: Damn, beat me by 5 seconds ;)

Comment: @LinkinTED thanks alot but before clicking and after clicking the width must be same but in the above update the width is varying !!

Comment: That's because the content doesn't fit. [Setting the width of the table](http://jsfiddle.net/Udxyb/422/) fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Double the number of TDs in the second row; and add a colspan="2" on each TH to explain it must have a 2 columns width

```
<thead>
    <tr class="firstline">
        <th colspan="2">Column1</th>
        <th colspan="2">Column2</th>
        <th colspan="2">Column3</th>
        <th colspan="2">Column4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr style="width:1002px; background-color:green; color:white">
        <td  class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 3 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 5 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 6 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 7 </td>
         <td  class="flip"> Section 8 </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple: Set all `td` in cols of 4 as `colspan="2"`